# Setting up Locations in Family Tree Maker 2017?

Tags: place-names, family-tree-maker

For those of us interested in switching to FTM2017:  In a recent demo of this version locally, entering Locations was shown as: only 4 places were to be used and they were City, County, State, Country; ie Winchester, Frederick, Virginia, USA and could be done no other way correctly.

The question of how to enter the following came up: How to correctly enter information re the birth of a Child in the early 1600s born in what was much later to become Winchester, Frederick, Virginia, USA.  The answer given was that it had to follow the above "City, County, State, Country" which would then read totally incorrect as there was no Virginia, no USA and probably no Winchester or Frederick County until much later.  Surely this is NOT the way the program should handle Locations or not only would this example be incorrect but there would be no way to handle all the Location changes in Europe, the Middle East, etc., through history.

Comment: This may be a possible duplicate of https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/how-should-place-names-be-recorded as it does not seem to be specific to FTM although that's the example given

Comment: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/31/when-documenting-location-should-current-or-historical-place-names-be-used also looks relevant.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! If the two questions referenced don't answer your question, feel free to edit your question and say why not. You can find out more about how the site works in the [help] if needed.

Comment: There seem to be 2 issues here. Contemporary or Current? And how many nodes? The implication seems to be that this version of FTM will only cope with 4. For everywhere in the world? Surely not. If I want to record a pre Deutsche Reich event in Hamburg, then 1 node suffices (Hamburg was a city state in its own right). Conversely events in the former Prussia after the creation of the Reich can easily break 4 - town, subdivision, Schleswig Holstein, Prussia, Deutschland, is *I* *think* a minimum.