# Proper Citation for Hungary/Austria Birthplace

Tags: citation, hungary, renaming-places, austria

I am tracing ancestors born in the late 18th through mid 19th century from a village which at the time was in western Hungary. Following the end of WWI, the area was transferred to Austria and the name of the village changed. Hungary Catholic Church records give the Hungarian name/location, but online genealogies cite the Austrian name/location (which did not exist at the time of the individuals' birth). Which is correct (or more appropriate)?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Genealogy.SE! [This question](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/31/56) might be of interest to you. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @user995 The other question about citation says you should use the original name which I would agree but also record both as places change names and even the one in the record may not necessarily even be the correct one for the residents at the time but by the current occupier. So one that was culturally correct too might be appropriate to "Additionally" note as you may see all three or more references which I personally encountered for example. Can you tell us the name of the village so we can specifically answer this question or can we mark it duplicate of the one American Luke referenced?